# Was it explained in the novel how Anton knew what hospital Llewelyn was at?

Tags: plot-explanation, no-country-for-old-men

In the movie *No Country for Old Men*, we just see Anton appear right as Carson is walking up the stairs. We can assume that he was watching the hospital that Llewelyn was at and saw Carson enter. So that's how he knew where Carson was but how did Anton know where to find Llewelyn after the gunfight at the Hotel? Is it elaborated more in the novel?

Comment: I feel that there are numerous points throughout the film where you could ask how one character was able to know what another had done. My feeling is that there's just an implied sameness to the four men. They can find each other, or each find something that another has hidden, just by each of them asking himself what he would do.